# Symfony2/Twig - how to set template file contents as variable?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Symfony 2.8 I've got `SharedBundle`, where I keep views and other things I share between other bundles, including the whole layout that should be extended by other bundles' views.
That shared layout has some typical blocks, from which `sidebar` block should be different for different bundles.

Currently I did an ugly workaround:

In `SharedBundle` sidebar container:

```
{% if sidebarcontent is defined %}
    {{ sidebarcontent|raw }}
{% else %}
    SIDEBAR NOT FOUND
{% endif %}
```

And in other bundles (here: `BundleA`) in every view that extends the shared main view:

```
{% extends 'SharedBundle:layout.html.twig' %}
{% block sidebar %}
    {% include 'BundleA:_partials:sidebar.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
{% set sidebarcontent =  block('sidebar') %}
```

But that doesn't look good, I think. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a valid approach. The only simplification I can think of is not using the variable `sidebarcontent`.

You can use `block('sidebar')` inside the `if` statement:

```
{% if block('sidebar')|length > 0 %}
    {{ sidebarcontent|raw }}
{% else %}
    SIDEBAR NOT FOUND
{% endif %}
```

Make sure the block exists before checking it's content, so initialise it with an empty string:

```
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm passing template by variable, because the twig that is actually rendering it is a partial, which is included by partial, which is included by... etc. I figured out some time ago I can't override blocks, is the overriding template is included.